# Extjs - I Can't Get Store in The Controller Even Though It Defines (MVC)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am working on MVC Pattern. 
I have two function bellow, one is working and the other is not working. Take a look at my controller code;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.program', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    stores: [
        'program'
    ],

    deleteWithConfirm: function(button, e, options) {
    var viewList = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#programGrid')[0];
        var selection = viewList.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
        if(selection)
        {
        Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to do that?', 
        function(btn, text ) {
            if(btn == 'yes') {
            console.log('yes clicked');

            this.getProgramStore().remove(selection); //console error message: "TypeError: this.getProgramStore is not a function"
            this.getProgramStore().sync();

            }
            if(btn == 'no') {
            console.log('no clicked');
            }
        }
        );
    }
    },

    justDelete: function(button, e, options) {
        var viewList = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#programGrid')[0];
        var selection = viewList.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
        if(selection)
        {
            this.getProgramStore().remove(selection);
            this.getProgramStore().sync();
        }
},


init: function(application) {
    this.control({
        "#tombolHapusProgram": {
            click: this.deleteWithConfirm //this is not working

    //click: this.justDelete //this is working
        }
    });
}

});
```

justDelete function is working good. But when I modify that code, adding a message box confirm, the code is not working even though I defines store.

Would you please show me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the scope for the callback:

```
Ext.Msg.confirm('A', 'B', function() {
}, this);
```

Comment: Error message is disappear, but I can't see console log "klicked yes" or "clicked no". It's mean the code is not run into it. 
Is there any other solution?

Comment: @kenzominang Replace `console.log` with `alert`.

Comment: Replace `}. this);` with `}, this);` ;)

Comment: @wared Thank you very much. It's working good. :) The code look like this **Ext.Msg.confirm('A','B',function(){ console.log('run into this'); }, this );**

Answer (score 0):

Your store instance is bound to the grid anyways so just do the following:

```
viviewList.getStore().remove(selection)
```